# Velocity breaking meteor deploy

Tags: meteor, meteor-velocity

I am having trouble with my Meteor up, which is perfectly functional on localhost and on Modulus. When I try to deploy to a *.meteor.com instance the upload fails and I get a very cryptic error. The first line is the gist of it I guess

```
Error: not a tracked temp dir: /Users/valentin/.meteor/packages/velocity_core/.0.4.5.1dbi101++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova
```

I have tried installing and reinstalling velocity and tried deploying it with/without, the error persists. There are a bunch of hidden files in the folder the error points too. Deleting the one mention in the error simply creates new ones and throws an error again (naming a different folder though) Does anyone have an idea what it is about?

Comment: Try removing all of your testing packages, re-deploy, then re-add them back in. Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with another meteor package. It was solved after I delete everything from `myapp/.meteor/local/` directory. 
I think you can leave your local db there (`myapp/.meteor/local/db`), but I did not check if it still be working. (I've deleted all and probably it is the same as running `meteor reset` for your local project.)

Answer (score 1):

OK, this seems to work: You have to manually downgrade the meteor version to 1.0.2.1, by editing `.meteor/release` and changing the version number. (There's a [fix in dev](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3761), so it should be solved in a more complete fashion soon.)

Answer (score 0):

Were you trying to deploy while your meteor app still ran in localhost? I faced the same problem for another package but resolved it by stopping my local meteor app first then deploy.